Handling errors with function CVErr
I use the following function.
Function CalculateDouble(Number)
If IsNumeric(Number) Then
    CalculateDouble = Number * 2    ' Return result.
Else
    CalculateDouble = CVErr(2001)    ' Return a user-defined error 
End If    ' number.
End Function

I need this function to return the used-defined error type "2001" or any other, but it doesn't.
Please help to repair this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Are you calling this function from VBA?  That's the example code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/cverr-function and it works fine for me...

...if calling as a UDF then I think the error number must be one of this list; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb211091(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN   Otherwise you just get #VALUE

Part of your problem is that you are not declaring the types of your function parameters nor your return type.  By setting parameter and return types correctly you can avoid needing to test for a number within the function e.g.
Public Function CalculateDouble(Number As Double) as Double
    CalculateDouble = Number * 2
End Function

Now you can't call the function without ensuring that the value you provide to the function is a double.  This moves the test for IsNumeric to outside the function.
Dim myDoubleNo as Double
If IsNumeric(Number) then
   myDoubleNo = CalculateDouble(CDbl(Number))
else
   <Code for when IsNumeric is false goes here>
End if


How would a function that returns Double be able to return an Excel error code? What would be the code "outside the function" when the function is called from a worksheet?

Does the original question have any mention of excel?  I didn't see anything.

@freeflow pls see question tags VBA

vba applies across many office applications.  It is not Excel specific.  You should note that SO guidlines for VBA specify that you should give the tag relating to the application if you wat more precise answers.

@freeflow You are technically correct, but the chance that this is not actually about Excel is vanishingly low.

@Andrei Please add [Excel] tag to your question if it is indeed about Excel, and if it is not, please add the tag for the application in which you are using the VBA.

 As someone who spent a lot of time writing VBA in Word and never using Excel, the chances of me thinking a VBA question is about Excel is vanishingly small :-}
